# Laravel eloquent change date timestamps GLOBAL to d-m-Y H:i:s

Tags: laravel-5, date-formatting

I have read several post to change the timestamps date format but i couldn't find how to change this for all Models GLOBAL.

I want to display created_at and update_at like this format d-m-Y H:i:s

Is that possible and how can i achieve that?

Comment: make trait and use needed models

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is 2 solution

**1 solution)** using traits

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Traits;

trait DatesAttributes
{
    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime:d-m-Y H:i:s',
        'updated_at' => 'datetime:d-m-Y H:i:s', 
    ];
}
```

Make trait, and use only that models where need to convert dates.

**2 solution)** using parent model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CastModel extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime:d-m-Y H:i:s',
        'updated_at' => 'datetime:d-m-Y H:i:s', 
    ];
}
```

All models where need to convert dates must be extend CastModel.

**3 solution)** In this time you can override **trait HasAttributes** and **app.php** config file

```
protected function getDateFormat()
{
    return $this->dateFormat ?: env('date_format', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

in `app.php` config add

```
'date_format' => 'd-m-Y H:i:s'
```

and finally use

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CastModel extends Model
{
    use App\Models\Traits\HasAttributes;
}
```

all models must be extend `CastModel`

Comment: These solutions are nice, but i want to setup it once and not use a trait everytime or extend. If this is the only solution i will except it.

Comment: Your laravel version??

Comment: 5.6 i use, thank you for your contribution. Solution 3 is also nice.